# Repeat a python function on its own output

Tags: python, html, function

I made a function that scrapes the last 64 characters of text from a website and adds it to `url1`, resulting in `new_url`. I want to repeat the process by scraping the last 64 characters from the resulting URL (`new_url`) and adding it to `url1` again. The goal is to repeat this until I hit a website where the last 3 characters are "END".

Here is my code so far:

```
#function
def getlink(url):
    url1 = 'https://www.random.computer/api.php?file='
    req=request.urlopen(url)
    link = req.read().splitlines()

    for i,line in enumerate(link):
        text = line.decode('utf-8')
    
    last64= text[-64:]
    new_url= url1+last64
  
    return new_url



getlink('https://www.random/api.php?file=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345678910')
#output
'https://www.random/api.php?file=zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba012345678910abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

My trouble is figuring out a way to be able to repeat the function on its output. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, try this: `getlink(getlink(url))` or simply `newlink = getlink(url) ` `getlink(newlink)`

Comment: You need to implement a recursive function (a function that calls itself). See https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_recursion.asp#:~:text=Python%20also%20accepts%20function%20recursion,data%20to%20reach%20a%20result.

Comment: @Sahee this would be good if it was a small number of websites I could go through manually. but I have to go through hundreds!!

Comment: @balderman I think a while loop should be enough

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are posting in the internet sensitive information, try to use dummy examples (use a fake url for examp`le) for your own safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop should work. I've removed the first token as it may be sensible information. Just change the `WRITE_YOUR_FIRST_TOKEN_HERE` string with the code for the first link.

```
from urllib import request


def get_chunk(chunk, url='https://www.uchicago.computer/api.php?file='):
    with request.urlopen(url + chunk) as f:
        return f.read().decode('UTF-8').strip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chunk = 'WRITE_YOUR_FIRST_TOKEN_HERE'
    while chunk[-3:] != "END":
        chunk = get_chunk(chunk[-64:])
        print(chunk)
        # Chunk is a string, do whatever you want with it,
        # like chunk.splitlines() to get a list of the lines
```

`read` get the byte stream, `decode` turns it into a string, and `strip` removes leading and trailing whitespaces (like `\n`) so that it doesn't mess with the last 64 chars (if you get the last 64 chars but one is a `\n` you will only get 63 chars of the token).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. It can perform what you mention above?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getlink(url):
    url1 = 'https://www.uchicago.computer/api.php?file='
    response = requests.post(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    text = doc.decode('utf-8')
    last64= text[-65:-1]
    new_url= url1+last64
  
    return new_url

def caller(url):
    url = getlink(url)
    if not url[-3:]=='END':
        print(url)
        caller(url)
```